# android serial port Interrupt receiving over 32 byte,will enter next Interrupt

Tags: android, serial-port

```
public void run() {
    super.run();
    while (!isInterrupted()) {

        int size;
        try {
            byte[] reBuf = new byte[1024];
            if (mInputStream == null) return;
            size = mInputStream.read(reBuf);
            if (size > 0)
                onDataReceived(reBuf, size);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mInputStream.close();
                mInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the number of bytes received is less than 32 then everything is all right. But, if the number of bytes received is more than 32 then it will be interrupted twice. I am writing modbus on Android. How can I get only one interruption, no matter how long the data is received?

Comment: Strange that you have in a loop this statement, I don't see any reason why it cannot be outside.  byte[] reBuf = new byte[1024];